# Difference of scala typed pattern match between Array and List

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-erasure

I have the following statements.

```
val a: Any = Array("1", "2", "3")
a match {
  case p: Array[Int] => println("int")
  case l: Array[String] => println("string")
}

val b: Any = List(1, 2, 3)
b match {
  case l: List[String] => println("string")
  case p: List[Int] => println("int")
}
```

The first block about Array compiles without warnings and outputs "string", while the second one about List compiles with warnings related to type erasure and outputs "string" as well.

I know something about type erasure in JVM. At runtime, JVM cannot really know the generic type of a container(such as List). But why does Array can avoid type erasure at runtime and get the right type matched?

I tried to find the answer from scala source code. The only thing I found is that Array uses ClassTag but List does not.

I'd like to how ClassTag works. Is ClassTag a workaround of type erasure? And why containers like List haven't been implemented with ClassTag to avoid type erasure.

Answer (score 4):

Scala runs on the JVM and inherits its constraints. Java employs type erasure so all parametrized types are the same in runtime. Type information is erased from them. That was done to keep compatibility with older Java versions that could not use type parameters at all.

But arrays is the special case in Java, they keep type information. So scala arrays do. That was necessary to keep memory efficient unboxed values inside arrays.

You should just assume that all type information is lost during runtime. So use some tags to match against them.

---

`ClassTag`s are not related to array wrapping. All types information is supplied by JVM itself.

There is custom practise in Java to use AnyRef and dynamic cast every time you get difficulties expressing type relations. Scala provides more expressive power for describing types statically without runtime conversions. And Scala coding style encourage using heavy type constructions for keeping code typesafe.

`ClassTag`s and `TypeTag`s are instruments that can be used only with statically typed code. They contain class and type information that the compiler has derived during compilation time. If it could derive types statically than it can provide type tags for you to access this types.

This is useful when you write some kind of library and have no clue how would it be used. So you require `ClassTag` as implicit parameter and it would be filled by compiler with appropriate type basing on other argument supplied to the function call. Implicit parameters is placed as requirement by library code and filled automatically by outer code that calls the library.

Comment: Great answer! So the idea is to keep compatible with java arrays, scala arrays introduce ClassTag to achieve that?

Comment: explained ClassTags briefly

Answer (score 0):

In these cases you may want to consider using the `Typeable` type class you get with [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) for type safe casts. E.g.:

```
scala> import shapeless.syntax.typeable._
import shapeless.syntax.typeable._

scala> val b: Any = List(1, 2, 3)
b: Any = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> b.cast[List[String]]
res1: Option[List[String]] = None

scala> b.cast[List[Int]]
res2: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3))
```

As you can the `cast[T]` method, added to every type by shapeless through `implicits`, returns an `Option[T]` whose value is `None` if the cast fails, `Some` if it's successful.

If you feel like it you could look at the source code of [Typeable](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/typeable.scala). However, I suggest you get a nice cup of coffee before doing it. :)